# get total bundle size in create-react-app (CRA)

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, cra

Running `yarn build` in my CRA app prints out useful information including bundle sizes.
Is there a way to extract just the Javascript and CSS bundle sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Install [`source-map-explorer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer):

- npm - `npm i --dev source-map-explorer`
- yarn - `yarn add -D source-map-explorer`

Install [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

From the project directory run (install `brew install coreutils` and replace `numfmt` with `gnumfmt` in OS X):

`$ source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*' --gzip --json | jq '.results[] | .totalBytes' | paste -s -d+ - | bc | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B` to get the total size of Javascript bundle (gzipped)

`$ source-map-explorer 'build/static/css/*' --gzip --json | jq '.results[] | .totalBytes' | paste -s -d+ - | bc | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B` to get the total size of CSS bundle  (gzipped)